# Why Network Packet Analyzer not capturing Http Post Request through Web Client

Tags: c#, http, networking, wireshark

I am using upload file method of web client to post transaction to a particular URL. I am using wireshark to capture this network communication, but surprisingly wireshark is not showing this requested URL in my UAT System. As it is a HTTP Request I have filtered it with particular Ip address and Http and it is showing all other request which I am doing through my web browser but not particular request which I am doing through my webclient class.

Sample Code :-

```
string url = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["https_url"];
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();

                wc.QueryString = q;

                string ResultString = string.Empty;
                byte[] postBytes = wc.UploadFile(url, "POST", strFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your code correctly, your are uploading your file via HTTPS? If that is the case, your traffic will only show up as SSL(which will not be filtered as HTTP) unless you  configure your wireshark to decrypt SSL traffic correctly.

Some information: http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL

If you don't want to deal with setting up wireshark to decrypt HTTPS traffic, I recommend tweaking your url to send a POST via http, which will then show up in your wireshark sniff.